# What encoding should I use to encode temperautre symbol in my iOS development？

Tags: ios, encode, temperature

```
char symbol[] = {0xa1,0xe3};  //temperatue symbol code

NSString *degree = [NSString stringWithCString:symbol encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//when "degree" displayed on screen,messy code.
```

what kind of encoding should i use ? It seems that `NSASCIIStringEncoding` doesn't work.

or any other methods can helps to solove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why go to all of this trouble? Just type in the degree symbol directly into your code?

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d °C", someVal]; // Char U+00B0
```

Even better would be Unicode `U+2103` (`℃`) or `U+2109` (`℉`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Because the symbol value if read from a local file,and i need to encode it.